# .load() , fadeOut() and fadein() doesn't work in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, load

I have searched for this before posting..
I have a page in my site where I need to refresh the data every X seconds.
I am using 
`

```
var s= setInterval(function()
{

    $('#responsecontainer').fadeOut("slow").load('table_data.php?pair_id=<?echo $pair_id?>').fadeIn("slow");

}, 5000);

var s= setInterval(function()
{

    $('#responsecontainer2').fadeOut("fast").load('last_modifed.php').fadeIn("fast");

}, 5000);
```

`

It works fine in FF and Chrome but not in IE8. 
I don't mind to see that it loads the data every time, but it doesn't even do tha, I tried 
writing

```
$('#responsecontainer').load('table_data.php');
```

and it loads old data from the file even though I change it.

The page is [here](http://s-maof.com/Forum/forex.php) (it's in hebrew, btw) 
any help??

Comment: If it's loading the old data, the problem might be browser caching. Try `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})` before the first `.load()` call. If that fixes it, you should look at fixing the [HTTP response headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses) that you're sending, specifically the cache-related ones (`Cache-Control`, `Pragma`, `ETag`, `Last-Modified`, `Expires`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `table_data.php` page is returning `304 Not Modified`, meaning you have it set to cache. Add headers to that file to [prevent cacheing](http://www.blog.highub.com/php/php-solutions/php-prevent-browser-and-proxy-cache/) and it should work fine.

Comment: hi guys, thanks it worked - the data now refreshes. But the fade in , dae out still doesn't work in exploer. Instead I get a flicker in the div below whick contains flash (#history graph, this happens in every browesers).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the page is not cached. A typical approach is to use a unique timestamp or a value like

```
'table_data.php?pair_id=<?echo $pair_id?>&no-cache=' + (new Date()).getTime()
```